# How to run remotely debug Zeppelin through eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, apache, jetty, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to setup Zeppelin code base in Eclipse.The workspace is created by cloning the code from GitHub.
Successfully able to run goals clean, validate, compile.
But I am not able to run the Zeppelin gui by jetty:run as goal. The server comes up but the GUI index.html page is not displayed.
What all configs should be modified in order to run Zeppelin through Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one article for how to diagnose zeppelin
https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/70658/how-to-diagnose-zeppelin.html